# Will 3rd party email services like Sendgrid just "relay" my messages?

Tags: email, smtp

I am going to be building a web application that allows users to create their own newsletters and mass email them to their subscribers.

I have a very high level question on how services like SendGrid, PostageApp, JangoSMTP works...  **Basically, can these services accept whatever HTML content I give it and then transmit them as emails ?**

When visiting the sites of some of these services, it mentions friendly UIs to help create email templates.  But that's not what I'm interested in.  I'm just interested in a 3rd party provider to relay any html documents my web app gives it.  This will eliminate the need for me to configure my own smtp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set the HTML body on the SMTP message to your content.